# Horizontal scrollview scroll changes tab focus

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabwidget, horizontalscrollview

I hav a tab widget within horizontal scrollview. The problem that i m having is this that when i am scrolling through scroll view, current tab in the tab widget changes and because of this ontabchange event handler executed.

To stop this i was trying to handle ontouchevent of scrollview which scrolls through  tabs and returns true. but not quite able to do so properly.

Can someone plz help with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check out this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035817/horizontalscrollview-inside-listview-minor-vertical-scroll-stops-horizontal-scr

Comment: i switched to sherlock action bar which solved all my problems:)

Answer (score 0):

try this in tab xml

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/src" />

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```