# How to disable the move threshold when getting touch events?

Tags: android, events, touch, threshold

I am creating an Android game that uses touch input. I noticed that, when I put down a finger and move it, there is a threshold of a couple of pixels until the first `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`  is generated. What is the correct way of disabling this threshold filter?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: To make the game feel responsive. The threshold hinders the gameplay.

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called touch slop. And here's the same question already answered: [Android ACTION_MOVE Threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785068/android-action-move-threshold)

Comment: hmm, not the answer i was hoping for, but it seems to be correct.