# How to calculate sensitivity for drawing on Android devices?

Tags: android, touch, drawing, android-canvas

The Android SDK recommends the use of

```
ViewConfiguration.getScaledTouchSlop()
```

for detecting if the finger on the touch screen has been moved. According to Android, the ScaledTouchSlop depends on the device, and with that upon resolution and screen sensitivity.

I have written a view where the user can use Canvas for painting on the screen, and I have realized that painting works differently well on different devices. Further investigation showed that ScaledTouchSlop seems to be defined by the device manufacturer and varies a lot between manufacturers. For example

- The ASUS Memo Pad 7 has a ScaledTouchSlop of 11 pixels on a 7 inch screen with approx. 1280x720.
- The Samsung Galaxy Note 2 has a ScaledTouchSlop of 32 on a 5.5 inch screen with approx. 1280x720.

Both screens have about the same resolution, so when looking at the ASUS device, I would have expected ScaledTouchSlop to be around 14 on the Samsung device (11 pixels * 7 inch / 5.5 inch), but it is 32. This results in not being able to fluently draw on the Samsung, as smaller strokes are often not recognized.

Sure, I can just define my own "slop" for drawing, and if I do drawing works perfectly well, also on the Samsung device. But I guess that would cause trouble on other devices, which are smaller or have a less sensitive screen.

Is there are a way how the touch slop should be calculated for drawing or does anyone have a recipe that works well on all devices?

Comment: This may not answer your question fully, but might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6785068/3879470